# Python get second item from each internal list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I have a list that contains internal list (read from a comma seperated file), of which I would like to get the second item. For example in `x = [[2,3,4][5,6,7]]` i would like to get 3 and 6. Simple stuff, which I thought I knew how to do. I know I could try using the following method to get the second numbers:

```
fp = open('random.txt') 
x = list(fp.read().split("\n"))
x.pop(0) #header line
x = [item.split(",") for item in x]

print([item[1] for item in x])
```

My problem is, I can get the first item by doing `item[0]` in the code above and that works fine. However, if I try `item[1]` I get a list index out of range error. I tried just testing if my list was correct in a normal for loop.

```
for item in x:
    print(item[1])
```

This ended up working fine, now I know I can just use this second version if I really wanted too, but I was wondering why the first version would give that error when it works just fine in the second version?

---

EDIT: included the rest of my code

Comment: You're list comprehension is fine.. not sure why you're getting an error. Make sure that all  sublists have at least 2 elements and that you're splitting the list correctly

Comment: Your edit made your question a completely different one. You probably have lines that don't contain a comma. We can't tell more without sample data that would exhibit the problem.

Comment: \n after last dataline - line after thathas  no `,` so no [1] either...

Comment: `print([item[1] for item in x if len(x) > 1] )` fixes it

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I notice you have confusing variable names and overwrite them with different structures. Maybe the error happened before/after you changed one of the variables with no clear name, and not where you presented it in this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem must have something to do with your other code. I just ran the following:

```
x = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
print([item[1] for item in x])
```

> [3,6]

```
for item in x:
    print(item)
```

> [2, 3, 4]
>
> [5, 6, 7]

```
for item in x:
    print(item[1])
```

> 3
>
> 6

All the code you posted runs fine without errors. You must be altering your list somehow that is not posted. I suggest you try `print(x)` before you process it to determine what the actual structure looks like and then process it accordingly from there.